# Conda channels 'default' vs 'defaults'

Tags: conda

In a conda `environment.yml` file, is there any difference between

```
channels:
  - default
```

and

```
channels:
  - defaults
```

or `default` and `defaults` are just synonyms?

**Edit:** from my observations so far, one shall use `defaults` (with `s` at the end), not sure why conda allows `default`, but it seems to have no effect - as if I haven't specified any channel at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that Conda should behave as though you haven't provided any channel at all. However, Conda isn't equating `default` to `defaults`.

With the exception of explicitly providing a URL in the channel specification list, Conda attempts to induce a URL from the string provided, namely

```
channels:
  - default
```

will induce

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/default
```

This is so that one can easily specify *user channels* on Anaconda Cloud. In this case, it tries to source from the user `default`. [Such an account exists](https://anaconda.org/default), but hosts no packages.<sup>**1**</sup> Effectively, this YAML provides no channels with any packages.

So, why are any packages found?

This occurs because the `conda env create` command **still includes configured channels**. So, if you have `defaults` or `conda-forge` included in the configuration settings (e.g., in `~/.condarc`), Conda will also search for packages in those channels.<sup>**2**</sup> Hence, we get the behavior that it acts as though one omitted the `channels:` section altogether.

---

<sub>**[1]**: That, unfortunately, would make for a dangerous typosquat.</sub>
<sub>**[2]**: There isn't actually a simple way to override the configured channels in the `conda env` commands (see [Conda Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9065)).</sub>